# add pop up window when condition fails in .ascx page in asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net

On magepage.acsx.cs page,I want to display pop up window,below is the code I have written.But it is now working.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((peoplePicker1.SelectedPersonPersonnelNumber == 1) || (peoplePicker2.SelectedPersonPersonnelNumber == 1) || (peoplePicker3.SelectedPersonPersonnelNumber == 1))
    {
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('  Employee profile information not available in eDRMS2, please get in touch with call center team-2222 to get the issue resolved.');window.location='ManageAccess.aspx';</script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to show a alert box ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((peoplePicker1.SelectedPersonPersonnelNumber == 1) || (peoplePicker2.SelectedPersonPersonnelNumber == 1) || (peoplePicker3.SelectedPersonPersonnelNumber == 1))
    {
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('  Employee profile information not available in eDRMS2, please get in touch with call center team-2222 to get the issue resolved.');window.location.href='ManageAccess.aspx';</script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than just saying "try this", could you perhaps explain *what* you've changed, and *why* you think it will fix the problem?